# Downloading and using the JS file(s) for only one Bootstrap 5 component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, bootstrap-5, cdn

**To avoid having unnecessary JS in my files, is there a way to only use the JS for the Bootstrap 5 carousel component only, without having to include everything else from the main Bootstrap JS file?**

Using CDN isn't an option, and I need to have the JavaScript downloaded locally.

I have a **Bootstrap 5** carousel working in my project, which currently uses the `bootstrap.min.js` source code applied locally.

I ran a Google Lighthouse test, which showed only about 10-15% of the JS was actually being used, so it would be good if I can still keep the carousel working while removing all of this redundant JavaScript.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#individual-or-compiled